# Unable to access SMB share with DNS Cache service disabled from Windows Server 2022 but it works on Server 2019

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system, active-directory, server-message-block

I have a requirement to disable the Windows DNS Cache on a new Windows Server 2022 RDS VM.

Trying to access a SMB share hosted on a Windows Server 2022 file server, all my servers are joined to a AD domain and on the same network with a permit any to any on same subnet firewall rule.

When I disable the DNS cache on 2022 RDS server, I am unable to access any SMB shares. The share works perfectly fine when the DNS cache is enabled.
[SMB error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P96Ur.png)

This isn't a network, firewall or permissions issue as all the required ports are open and security permissions setup. File and printer sharing is enabled on both sides, on the Server 2022 file server I tried enabling the SMB-QUIC-In and iWARP-in built in Windows firewall rules so that all file and printer sharing built in inbound rules are enabled on the file server.

From the Server 2022 RDS server I can successfully resolve and ping the hostname of the file server with the cache disabled, successfully ping the IP of the file server too just can't seem to establish SMB session.

When I disabled the DNS cache on the old Server 2019 server years ago SMB share access worked perfectly fine and continues to work with it disabled to this day.

Running a packet capture from the file server side and the RDS server side with the cache disabled - there is no traffic generated when clicking into the mapped SMB share on file explorer.

Does anyone know why SMB shares stop working with DNS cache disabled on Server 2022 but this works on Server 2019?

Comment: Run a capture when you use the following from the command prompt: `dir \\n.n.n.n\sharename`

Comment: Same as before 'the network path was not found' - nothing on either side for the packet capture
The same result with the hostname or IP address, I am open to any further suggestions, thanks

Comment: What does both `nslookup SMB.server.host.name` and `nslookup IP` from the SMB client show?

Comment: There are some good troubleshooting approaches for DNS-related SMB issues here [**SMB file server share access is unsuccessful through DNS CNAME alias**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/dns-cname-alias-cannot-access-smb-file-server-share)

Comment: nslookup with hostname resolves A record to the correct internal IP
nslookup for the IP resolves back to the hostname

Thanks Andrew - I did find the article whilst researching this issue but I'm mapping the share with the FQDN of the file server not a CNAME

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: @tezx I didn't think that link was your problem as the error messages are different, but the information there would be useful, especially regarding packet captures.  I'd start with that and see what's actually happening.  Maybe do the same thing from a host that works and see what's different.  Or go through the event logs on the misbehaving server to see if anything else is misbehaving.  You don't have multiple IPs for the server in DNS, do you?  And relying on DNS round-robin for load balancing?  DNS caching can affect that by reordering IP results.

Comment: No duplicate records in DNS for these servers, when comparing the 2019 server to 2022 in the packet capture, the only real difference on both sides is that the 2019 server can establish SMB over 445 with/without the DNS cache enabled

On 2022 when its disabled you can't see any traffic for the SMB session even begin to establish. When DNS cache is enabled on 2022 the packet capture is more or less the same as the 2019 server the SMB session establishes and network drives are working.

Will take a look through event viewer, open to any further ideas, thank you

Comment: Is this the "Azure" edition?

Comment: Non-azure edition - datacentre 2019 and 2022

Comment: Seeing this in SMB client event viewer logs

The client cannot resolve the server address in DNS or WINS. This issue often manifests immediately after joining a computer to the domain, when the client's DNS registration may not yet have propagated to all DNS servers. You should also expect this event at system startup on a DNS server (such as a domain controller) that points to itself for the primary DNS. You should validate the DNS client settings on this computer using IPCONFIG /ALL and NSLOOKUP.

Comment: The computer hasn't just been joined to the domain, the DNS registration has populated to all DNS server (its just one DNS server) and I can resolve the SMB server address?!

Also the TCP/IP NetBIOS helper service is running and set to automatic on client side

Comment: I doubt any of those things will address the inability to access the share using the IP address. At a minimum, there should at least be an arp request. Talk about the number of policy settings are present that are different from the default?

Comment: What happens when you add the IP to the host file or try to connect to share by using the ip

Comment: The share doesn't work even when using the IP and its the same when adding the IP/hostname combo to the hosts file
I can ping and resolve the hostname and IP with our without the hosts entry